# Let $f$ be a function such that $|f(x)|\leq |x|^2$. Does the derivative exist at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $|f(x)| \le |x|^2$. Then,
>
> (A) $f$ need not be differentiable at the origin.
>
> (B) $f'(0) > 0$.
>
> (C) $f'(0) = 0$.
>
> (D) $f'(0) < 0$.

My Attempts: $|f(x)|\leq |x|^2$ gives $|f(0)|\leq 0$ whereas $|f(0)|\geq 0.$ So combining both we get,$f(0)=0.$ Now,using this fact that $f(0)=0,$ I have proved that $f'(0)=0.$So in my opinion,$(C)$ is the right choice. Am i going in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You have proved that $f'(0)=0$ in a proof not shown here?

Comment: you are certainly right as $f(0)=0$ , we have $|f(x)/x|=|[f(x)-f(0)]/x|$ goes to zero as $x$ tends to zero (using sandwich theorem for limit), hence derivative of $f$ at the point zero is zero.

Comment: @timon Thanks a lot.That is what i did. +1 from me.

Comment: You started by posting in TeX, but now you've reverted to posting images. Is there a reason for this? There are a smattering of users recently who seem to be posting images copied and pasted from what looks like the same source. In particular, lots of multiple choice questions in this form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your statement is correct. Intuitively, the picture you should have in mind is that $f$ is sandwiched between the parabola $x^2$ and the $x$-axis; no matter how $f$ is wiggling or jumping away from the origin, it's squeezed in such a manner that it not only passes through the origin, but is flat there too.

To formalize this, you have correctly shown that $f(0) = 0$. Then
$$\limsup_{h \to 0} \left|\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}\right| \le \limsup_{h \to 0} \frac{|h|^2}{|h|} = \limsup_{h \to 0} |h| = 0$$
In particular, this shows that the limit (not only the limit supremum) exists and is zero, so $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: The lim **sup** looks unnecessary

Comment: @SimonS You're right, it's ultimately not needed. But I think it's a nice intermediate step to include before the computation of the limit, just to be very sure that we never write $\lim$ applied to something that doesn't exist.